# R: cleaning pdf text

Tags: r, stringr, tidytext, pdftools

I have pdf text that I need converted into "tidy" format. But I'm unsure about how to read in the pdf text without compromising the information I need. For example:

```
# install pacman package if you require it
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")

# p_load installs and loads packages

pacman::p_load(tidyverse, pdftools, tabulizer)

pdf_txt_raw <- pdf_text("https://www.statcan.gc.ca/eng/statistical-programs/document/5027_D1_V10-eng.pdf") %>% 
               read_lines()

pdf_txt_raw
```

Using `read_lines()` seems to give an error because whenever there are two lines in the "legal name" column, it messes up the tidy format I'm looking for. For example, the Loblaw Inc [4] should be fine to clean up because each operating name is separated by a comma and it is within the Loblaws line, giving me a clean category.

But the very fist legal name category is wrong due to a line break in the PDF - i.e., "Buy-Low Foods Limited Partnership" should be the legal name and the operating names within that category should be "AG Foods, Buy-Low Foods, Buy & Save Foods, Fine Foods, G&H Shop N' Save, Nesters Market".

Any tips on how to clean this properly and get the tidy format I'm looking for?

Comment: I need to go to bed now. But you can try `pdf_text("5027_d1_v10-eng.pdf") %>% strsplit(split = "\r\n")`. `pdf_text()` is from the pdftools package. This gives you pretty clean data. You need to think how you restructure the table.

Comment: I actually tried this but it gives the same problem as the using `read_lines()`

Comment: It seems to me that you have high expectation from these two functions. As far as I know, cleaning up data from PDF data requires some good amount of work. I think that is why your question has not been answered since I commented last time. My advice for you is to look for some kind of patterns in the output from `pdf_text()` or `read_lines()`. There will be some kind of patterns. At the same time, you will face some nasty situations as well. This is something you gotta face when you deal with PDF data.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a cheating way. Let me drop it for you. I copied and pasted each page of the PDF file in EXCEL 2013 on my Windows and created a file. This file contains data in a very nice way. I think this is the life saver for you. First, I imported it to R with `read_xlsx()`. Then, I changed the column name to `Legal Name`. You can have something else if you want. Then, I removed rows that contain headers in the PDF file such as `Operating Name|`, `Operating Name` and so on. Then, I created two columns. One is `id`. Basically one company's information stays in two consecutive rows. I used this pattern to create the variable. I also created `type`, which contains two types of names. Finally, I converted the data to a wide-format data. This gives us the following result. I am not sure if this approach works all the time. But at least with your PDF data, yes it does.

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf <- read_xlsx("SO_pdf.xlsx")

rename(mydf, legal_name = "Legal Name") %>% 
filter(!grepl(x = legal_name, pattern = "Operating Name|The Food Retailers|The Department Stores|The Other Non-Food Retailers")) %>% 
mutate(id = rep(1:(n()/2), each = 2),
       type = rep(c("legal_name", "operating_name"), times = (n()/2))) %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = "id", names_from = "type", values_from = "legal_name")

#      id legal_name                        operating_name                                                                            
#   <int> <chr>                             <chr>                                                                                     
# 1     1 Buy-Low Foods Limited Partnership AG Foods, Buy-Low Foods, Buy & Save Foods, Fine Foods, G&H Shop N' Save, Nesters Market   
# 2     2 Loblaws Inc.                      At the Pumps, Atlantic Gas Bars, Dominion, Extra Foods, Joe Fresh, Loblaws, Loblaws à Ple~
# 3     3 Metro Ontario Inc.                Drug Basics, Food Basics, Metro, Super C, The Pharmacy                                    
# 4     4 Overwaitea Food Group Limited Pa~ Cooper's Foods, Overwaitea Foods, PriceSmart Foods, Save-On-Foods, Urban Fare             
# 5     5 Sobeys Capital Incorporated       Candico Food Markets, Canada Safeway, Canada Safeway Liquor Store, Fast Fuel, Foodland, F~
# 6     6 Hudson's Bay Company              Home Outfitters/Déco Découverte, The Bay/ La Baie, Zellers                                
# 7     7 Sears Canada Inc.                 Sears, Sears Home Stores, Sears Hometown Stores, Sears Outlet                             
# 8     8 Wal-Mart Canada Corp              Walmart                                                                                   
# 9     9 American Eagle Outfitters Canada~ Aerie, American Eagle Outfitters                                                          
#10    10 Apple Canada Inc.                 Apple Store
```